# PRINT only SUM by year (group by Territory) in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, aggregate-functions

```
SELECT               year(soh.OrderDate) 'year',sum(soh.TotalDue) 'Total',st.[Group] TerritoryGroup
FROM                 Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
LEFT OUTER JOIN      Sales.SalesTerritory st
ON                   soh.TerritoryID=st.TerritoryID
GROUP BY             year(soh.OrderDate),(soh.TotalDue),[Group]
ORDER BY             year(soh.OrderDate),(soh.TotalDue)
```

This is what I came up with, but the years are scattered instead of ONE year per Territory total.
(I like to print the Total for each year in each Territory)
Is there a concise way to make this select statement?

Comment: You will have to provide more information if you want this answered.  Some example data or a bit more info on what you need.

Comment: It looks like she does not have enough points to show sample data. I think she wants something like  year -- total -- Terr  as columns. Then 2014 -- 5000 -- Texas. So, She wants all the data for Texas on ONE row. If I am not mistaking

Comment: @Eda: There is nothing like "not enough points to show sample data". You can always show sample data and expected results in your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want one row per year, then only include that in the `group by`:

```
SELECT year(soh.OrderDate) as year, sum(soh.TotalDue) as Total
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Sales.SalesTerritory st
     ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
GROUP BY  year(soh.OrderDate)
ORDER BY  year(soh.OrderDate);
```

If you want one row per year and territory group, then include only those two columns:

```
SELECT year(soh.OrderDate) as year, sum(soh.TotalDue) as Total, st.[Group] as TerritoryGroup
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Sales.SalesTerritory st
     ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
GROUP BY year(soh.OrderDate), [Group]
ORDER BY year(soh.OrderDate), Total;
```

Some notes:

- You do not need single quotes around the column aliases.  You should use single quotes only for string and date constants.
- If you are summarizing just by year, then you cannot have `TerritoryGroup` in the output.
- In neither case would you include `soh.TotalDue` in the `group by`.  You are summing that column, not aggregating by it.
- The `order by` clause should not contain `soh.TotalDue`; it should be the aggregated value (`Total`) instead.

Comment: Your answer, Gordon, looks like what she is trying to accomplish. =)

Comment: Gordon Linoff - THANK YOU. I was able to get the exact selection using the first code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

In GROUP BY you say you want one line per combination of year, totaldue and territory group.

Let's say you have these records:

```
orderdate   totaldue  territorygroup
2014-01-01  100       1
2014-01-15  200       1
2014-01-21  100       1
2013-03-03  100       1
2014-04-04  100       2
```

Then you get these result records:

```
year        totaldue  territorygroup
2014        100       1
2014        200       1
2013        100       1
2014        100       2
```

(BTW: sum(soh.TotalDue) = soh.TotalDue, because you group by TotalDue.)

So the solution for you is to say what you want to see in your result records actually. One record per ______. Thus you get your GROUP BY clause and the results you want.

Comment: Thanks. But I grouped by : year(soh.OrderDate),(soh.TotalDue),[Group] - And the years are still not in one row. There like 10 different rows of 2013 for example

Comment: Yes, you get 10 different rows per year (2013 for instance), but not 10 different rows per year-totaldue-group combination (2013 - 100 - 1). If you want one record per *year*, then group by *year* only.

Comment: This is the message I get when I group by YEAR only :Column 'Sales.Group' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Every column should either be in GROUP BY or get aggregated. So *either* have soh.TotalDue in GROUP BY *or* use an aggregation like SUM on it. Same for year and territory. So either have territory in your GROUP BY clause or decide which one to show for a group; such as the MIN or the MAX terrritory group. In other words: If you group by year only, then you get one record per year. So which territory shall be shown when there are different territories for one year?